# Function completes before callback returns result

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I’m new to node and I'm doing a random exercise, callbacks and asynchronous processing is new to me. I would appreciate some help in explaining how I can achieve this task.

What I’m trying to do is create an object based on the rows obtained from an excel spreadsheet and process them individually by adding/updating them in my table.

The problem I’m experiencing, something I’m seeing is common with node newbies is not understanding how to process synchronously.

I don’t understand why by default things would run asynchronously, surely most of the time you’d want something to happen before another action is performed?

I may not be approaching this correctly? 
In this scenario, I’m getting the a row from the excel dataset, as I loop through the dataset, I create an object for each row, part of this involves making a callback to another function (getAreaId) to obtain area_id based on the areaCode passed. In my console log, myOrganisation object always shows areaCode as undefined.

When I console.log inside my callback function, I see the correct value displayed. What is the best way for me to assign the value returned from my callback to my local object?

I’ve read I need to add some middleware like async. As this is my first attempt at node, I don’t want to start diving into adding libraries or make things any more complicated if I don’t need to.

```
function importData(){
    var myDataSet = getExcelData();
    var x = getOrganisationCode(function(existingOrgCode){

        for (j=0; j<myDataSet.length; j++){

            function organisationObj(orgCode, orgName, address1, areaCode){
                this.orgCode  = orgCode;
                this.orgName  = orgName;
                this.address1 = address1;
                //this.areaId   = getAreaId(areaCode, function(area_id){ return area_id});
                getAreaId(areaCode, function(area_id){ this.areaId = area_id});
            }

            myOrganisation =  new organisationObj(myDataSet[j]['OrgCode'], myDataSet[j]['OrgName'], myDataSet[j]['orgName'], myDataSet[j]['areaCode']);

            console.log(myOrganisation)

            if(isNewOrg(existingOrgCode.indexOf(myOrganisation.orgCode))){
                //doInsert
            } else {
                //doUpdate
            }
        }
    });
}

function getExcelData(){
    //This gets data from an excel spreadsheet
}

function isNewOrg(orgCode){
    //Checks if orgCode is not -1 and returns true/false accordingly
}

function getOrganisationCode(callback){
    //Do a DB call to return all orgCodes
    //SELECT orgCode FROM tOrg
}

function getAreaId(areaCode, callback){
    //Do a DB call to return an area id based on the code passed
    //SELECT areaId FROM tAreas WHERE areaCode = @input_parameter
}
```

Comment: Refer to this tutorial which will tell you how to write async functions->https://blog.risingstack.com/asynchronous-javascript/

Comment: "surely most of the time you’d want something to happen before another action is performed" — Most of the time you wouldn't want your webserver to stop accepting new HTTP requests which you waited for your database to return a result. Most of the time you wouldn't want the browser to lock up the entire user interface of the page while you waited for an HTTP request to get a response.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you make an asynchronous call, the operation is executed parallel to your current code flow.

If you do the async database call, your program does not wait for the database to complete. This is why a callback is used.

You simply tell the database: "hey, get me an id. Tell me when you´re finished. I will work on some other stuff meanwhile."
Then your program continues and goes out of the getAreaId function. Some time later, the database **calls you back** "hey, here is the id." and provides the id to the callback function.

```
organisationObj
    --> getAreaId
        |   --> db call
    <-- |          |
...                |
...                |
 (callback) <------|
```

Comment: The way you have worded your explanation I now have a better understanding of the meaning behind 'callback'. But I now feel callback is not the way I should be approaching this, would this be correct? if so, how best to approach this?

Comment: A callback is absolutely correct at this place. If you go deeper into that topic, you may find so called "deferred results". But inside, always a callback is used.

Answer (score 1):

[Rita Saxena](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5167807/riya-saxena) has shared a good link to explain async.

The main problem in the code is that there is an async call getAreaId inside a loop.

More generic explanation to understand the async concept (as addition to Riya Saxena shared), think about this function

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
   console.log('Value of i : ' + i); 
  },100);
}
```

You would expect that the ouput to be:

```
Value of i : 1
Value of i : 2
Value of i : 3
Value of i : 4
Value of i : 5
```

But the actual output is:

```
Value of i : 6
Value of i : 6
Value of i : 6
Value of i : 6
Value of i : 6
```

This is because by the time **setTimeout** is evaluated, the loop has finished, leaving the value of *i* at the end of the loop evaluation.

This example can be fixed in different ways that are not to answer this question.

In your case, by the time **console.log(myOrganisation)** is evaluated,

```
myOrganisation =  new organisationObj(myDataSet[j]['OrgCode'],
                   myDataSet[j]['OrgName'], myDataSet[j]['orgName'],
                   myDataSet[j]['areaCode']);
```

Has not returned from its evaluation (db call)

As a general guideline be cautious when mixing loops and async calls.